# Как избавиться от "мусора" при чтении через read с большим буфером?

Tags: c, unix, файловый-ввод-вывод

Читаю текстовый файл. Доступ получаю через `open`, а не `fopen`, так что `getc` и подобное не предлагать.

Считываю по 64 байта (`read(fd, str, 64)`) и на выходе получаю нужный текст с мусором в конце. Как от этого можно избавиться? Вариант чтения по одному байту не устроит.

Текст:

```
0000000000
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
7777777777
8888888888
9999999999
```

Вывод:

```
0000000000
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
7777777777
8888888888
9999999999444444444
555555555
```

Comment: Если используете malloc, вариант вместо него использовать calloc, если выделяете память на стеке (инициализируете char str[64] = {0};) и не будет мусора (по крайней мере если не пере-используете память, иначе нужно будет обнулять каждый раз - memset или bzero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно проверять, что read вернула. Она возвращает то количество байт, которое реально было считано.

Comment: Спасибо, использовал это значение как размер буфера, помогло. Уже понял что вопрос глупый. удивительно что не дошел до этого сам после 2 часов гугла